# Encrypting a pseudorandom message

Tags: block-cipher, randomness

Does encrypting a pseudorandom message need the same requirements from a block cipher?

For instance, can we decrease the number of rounds of AES if we want to cipher a random block, without any security loss?

Thank you

Comment: Will this reduced version be able to with stand CPA?

Comment: Yes, it should be ind-CPA secure. I assume the usage of a mode of operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with the other answer. If plaintexts are random (even if they only have high entropy) then [deterministic encryption](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/186) is possible and can achieve the equivalent of CPA security (this is an if-and-only-if, since low-entropy plaintexts require a randomized encryption, according to the very standard reasoning). Indeed, ECB mode is fine if the plaintext is known to be random. Conditioned on no duplicate plaintext blocks being encountered, it is easy to see all ECB ciphertext blocks will be indistinguishable from random.

But your question was about simplifying even the block cipher itself, not just the encryption scheme that is built on the block cipher. The usual definition of security for a block cipher considers adversarially chosen inputs. If we relax this security definition to consider only randomly chosen inputs, we get what is called **"weak PRF"** security. It is a quite reasonable assumption to say that reduced-round AES is a weak PRF. In fact, I have a faint memory of seeing exactly this assumption used in a paper somewhere, but I am unable to find the reference at the moment. For sure it's a non-standard assumption, but it is not an insane assumption.

Comment: _Plaintexts are random_ goes straight against the definition of _Choosen_ Plaintext Attack, where the adversary is free to choose plaintext, including repeat it. Even if we force the plaintext to be the output of a PRG (closely matching the question's _encrypting a pseudorandom message_), with the PRG's input under control of the adversary, the adversary can still force the same input twice at the input of the PRG, and make a distinguisher for the ciphertext.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the comment of François. Mikaro, I will try to retrieve the paper making use of a weak PRF.

Comment: @fgrieu: sure, it is a special case of CPA that doesn't encompass all of CPA. But we can certainly consider a special case of CPA with high-entropy plaintexts (which is exactly what deterministic encryption does) and find that things like ECB mode are secure in this model.

Answer (score 3):

A message - strange as it may sound - cannot be encrypted by a block cipher. A block cipher is a deterministic keyed permutation. As it is deterministic, it cannot be a CPA secure cipher: identical messages will result in identical ciphertext, leaking information about the message. This is why ECB mode encryption, which consists of block encrypting subsequent blocks of the message, is insecure. A secure mode of operation - CBC, CTR etc. - and an IV are required to turn block ciphers into secure ciphers.

As there is no way of distinguishing the message from random data the cipher doesn't need to be that secure. It is however still required to use a mode of operation and an IV if the block size is small. Otherwise the block cipher must be relatively large (˜256 bits for large messages) so that repetition of blocks in the plaintext cannot be detected.

If there is even a hint of information on the message (a header or the parity bits of a DES key, a slow starting PRNG, a PRNG started with too little entropy in the seed, a non-secure PRNG etc. etc.) then these kind of schemes will fail spectacularly. The scheme would be brittle to the extreme; if anything breaks or if any info leaks it will crumble. Obviously an attacker should certainly not be allowed to control the plaintext, so the scheme would not be CPA secure.

So yeah, you *could* reduce the number of rounds or even use a repeated XOR cipher. But the risk of leaking info would be huge.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Yes, the operating mode is mandatory. In fact, I have assumed it implicitely in my question. My question was about the block cipher (actually iterated with a mode).